# Gradle compileJava task skipping Hibernate mapping files

Tags: gradle, hibernate-mapping

In my gradle.properties file classesDir is set to /WEB-INF/classes. But for some reason only  compiled *.class files are copied there, omitting *.hbm.xml files that are located alongside java files (in com.project.model subfolder).

Hence application server (Tomcat 8) cannot start properly as mapping files are missing. What is wrong with my configuration?

Thanks,
Vitaliy.

Comment: `build_dir` is not a standard Gradle property, so you'd have to explain how that property is used by your build. Also, you'd have to explain where the `*.hbm.xml` source files are located.

Comment: I've modified the original text. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Resource files should be put in a separate source directory (`src/main/resources` by default). It's more difficult to make things work when they are mixed with Java sources. Also, resource processing isn't related to the `compileJava` task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I've added a separate task makeJava to copy the mapping files, and then used it as a dependent on compileJava, like this:

```
task copyHbm(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/com/project/model'
    into classesDir + '/com/project/model/'
    include '**/*.hbm.xml'
}

task makeJava(dependsOn: [compileJava, copyHbm])
copyHbm.mustRunAfter compileJava
```

Thanks for your help!